# How to do nor on matrices?

Tags: matrix

Supose I have matrices a b and c like

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
b = {7, 8, 9};
c = {{1},{4},{7}};
```

I want to get `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}` from `a` and `b`, also `{{2,3},{5,6},{8,9}}` from `a` and `c` ? In other words, I want to delete the part which is the same as `b` or `c` from `a`.

Comment: Could you clarify: Do you wish to delete elements or only entire matching rows/columns?  What do you expect to get for your example in a comment, `a = IdentityMatrix[3]; b = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}`?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `Complement`!

```
Complement[a,{b}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}

Or use `DeleteCases[a, b]`. Also `Cases[a, Except@b]` works!

For the list `c` use

```
MapThread[Complement, {a, c}]
```

Comment: Complement works fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait, it has a problem when dealing with                  A = IdentityMatrix[3];                                                    B = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}

Complement[A, B]
DeleteCases[A, B]
Cases[A, Except@B]                                                 I need the last column of A, but the result does match.

Comment: The solution works when `Length` of rows of `A` is equal to the length of `B`. To consider other cases you need to reformulate your question!

Comment: I supplement another case. Complement fails this time.

Comment: Thanks, I am a novice, MapThread[Complement[#1, #2] &, {a, c}] works, although I don't quite understand the grammar.

Comment: But why  a = IdentityMatrix[3]; b = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}} MapThread[Complement[#1, #2] &, {a, b}]  Mma returns      {{}, {}, {1}}

Comment: @user5463  Perhaps, if you wish to delete columns, you want `Transpose@Complement[Transpose@a, Transpose@b]`?