# How to get complement from two matrices?

Tags: matrix

This is a special case of my question [How to do nor on matrices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19721/how-to-do-nor-on-matrices)

```
 a = IdentityMatrix[3]; 
 b = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}} 
 MapThread[Complement[#1, #2] &, {a, b}]
```

*Mathematica* returns `{{}, {}, {1}}` , whereas I expect `{{0}, {0}, {1}}`, which is what I need.

Comment: `{{}, {}, {1}}` is what I would expect. Just replace `Complement` with e.g. `c` in `MapThread` and observe what are the direct arguments to `Complement`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do nor on matrices?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19721/how-to-do-nor-on-matrices)

Comment: Yes, this is a special case of another question of mine. But that method does not work for identity matrix.

Comment: @IstvánZachar The OP expects to get using `Complement[ConstantArray[0, 10], {0}]` a list of 9 zeros! So `Complement` based solution does not work for him as opposed to his previous question that you have noted as duplicate.

Comment: @PlatoManiac Doesn't it just mean that a `Complement` based solution was not a general solution to the general problem posed in the previous question? Maybe something like `ConstantArray[0,10] /. {h___,0,t___} :> {h,t}` would work.

Comment: @rm-rf You are right about the generality issue in both side of question and answer. Do you think it will be best for the forum if the OP agglomerate this question with his previous one and we close this question?

Comment: @PlatoManiac I think that would be useful. Your complement solution is neat and intuitive and it would be worth noting in your answer that it is a nice way to do it if the rows have distinct elements, but also provide a generalized solution.

Comment: Please edit title so it doesn't ask for "nor": "nor" suggest the logical/bitwise operation, which may be implemented by: `bitNor[{x_,y_}]:=Mod[BitNot[BitOr[x,y]],2]`.

Comment: Yes, I also feel the title is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following hack but remember this is a solution specific to your question no general solution!

```
newComplement[listA_, listB_] := Block[{check},
  check[list_, var_] := Module[{pos},
     pos = Position[list, var];
     If[Length@pos != 0, Drop[list, First@pos], list]
    ];
  If[(MemberQ[listA, #] & /@ listB) /. List ->  And,Fold[check, listA, listB], listA]
];
```

Testing it!

```
MapThread[newComplement[#1, #2] &, {a, b}]
```

> {{0}, {0}, {1}}

Comment: I have tested the new self-defined newComplement.It works for n-order identity matrix with the complement of any columns. Much Gratitude!

Comment: Plato, you don't need the `Function` in `MapThread`.  You can use `newComplement` directly.  I just made that change to an older answer of yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
a = IdentityMatrix[3];

b = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}};

MapThread[Complement, {a, b}] /. {} -> {0}
```

> ```
> {{0}, {0}, {1}}
> ```